# Generating evenly spaced points on grid using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot out n evenly spaced points inside a polygon which is the site shown below on a google map. Right now, I've managed to do this using gmplot.

[image: Google Map]

My aim is to create a grid of points inside the polygon.

My recent approach is using np.meshgrid and then selecting random points from the grid. Below is the code which I use to get the points. But,the result is not what I expected.

```
def random_points_within(poly, num_points):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    x = (np.linspace(min_x,max_x,1000))
    y=  (np.linspace(min_y,max_y,1000))
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y,sparse=True)
    xx=xx[0]
    points = []

    while len(points) < num_points:
        random_point = Point([random.choice(xx), random.choice(yy)])
        if (random_point.within(poly)):
            points.append(list(random_point.coords))
    print(min_x,max_x,max_y,min_y)
    return points
    #poly is a polygon created by the edges for the site
```

Update:

Tried iterating through all the points on the meshgrid and ended up getting the below image.

```
def random_points_within(poly, num_points):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    x = (np.linspace(min_x,max_x,num_points))
    y=  (np.linspace(min_y,max_y,num_points))
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y,sparse=True)
    xx = xx.reshape((np.prod(xx.shape),))
    yy = yy.reshape((np.prod(yy.shape),))
    points = []

    for (x,y) in zip(xx,yy):
       random_point = Point([x, y])
       if (random_point.within(poly)):
          points.append(list(random_point.coords))
    print(min_x,max_x,max_y,min_y)
    return points,xx,yy
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a way to get evenly spaced points ?

Comment: If you know the start and end values and the spacing I suppose you could use numpy.linspace

Comment: That's what I do right now, but I end up getting plots along a line.

Comment: how many points do you want to generate, and how evenly do you want them?  if you're not too tied to Python there's a `spsample` function in the `sp` R library…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have access to the poly object best I can do is make a guess:

```
def random_points_within(poly, num_points):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    x = (np.linspace(min_x,max_x,num_points))
    y=  (np.linspace(min_y,max_y,num_points))
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y,sparse=True)
    xx = xx.reshape((np.prod(xx.shape),))
    yy = yy.reshape((np.prod(yy.shape),))
    points = []

    for x in xx:
       for y in yy:
           random_point = Point([x, y])
           if (random_point.within(poly)):
              points.append(list(random_point.coords))
    print(min_x,max_x,max_y,min_y)
    return points,xx,yy
```

The only change I made compared to your program is that it loops both over xx and yy so you'll cover an area rather than a line.

Comment: I just did the same thing minutes later. Thank you though.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks. Although, I need to adjust the resolution every time since Google Maps API has a limit on elevation data requests

Comment: @Chinmay in that case, could you accept the answer?